# How do I make the x button to actually remove the li

Tags: javascript

Got this code, it does what I need it to do, but only the button cancel button doesn't work, I want it to remove the whole part of the list

I've been struggling, experimenting with whatever I could but nothing helped and I just don't know

My html:

```js
let myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
let i;
let close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

function newTask() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let value = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  let t = document.createTextNode(value);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (value === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myinput").value = "";

  let button = document.createElement("button");
  let text = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  button.className = "close";
  button.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(button);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = () => {
      var div = parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="uloha.css">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="task" id="task">
    <h1>To-do list</h1>
    <input type="text" , id="myinput" , placeholder="Task">
    <button onclick="newTask()" type="button" , class="button" id="button"> Add</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"Uncaught ReferenceError: parentElement is not defined"_

Comment: You need to define the element you want to delete with a valid `selector` .. `var div = parentElement;` --  Where is `parentElement` defined?

Comment: Skip the `for` loop completely and just do `button.onclick = () => li.remove();`

Comment: There is ZERO reason to look up the buttons. You have them when you create them. `button.addEventListener("click", function (evt) { evt.target.closest("li").remove(); });`

Comment: @epascarello -- This looks to me like copied and pasted code.  I feel that statement might be slightly out of OPs depth.  No offense to OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is event delegation. Instead of using onclick in a loop attaching new event handlers every time, just delegate the event to the body. Also, **parentElement** isn't an object and you aren't referencing the parent of the button anyway.

```js
let myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
let i;
let close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

function newTask() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let value = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  let t = document.createTextNode(value);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (value === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myinput").value = "";

  let button = document.createElement("button");
  let text = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  button.className = "close";
  button.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(button);
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let el = e.target;
  if (el.classList.contains("close")) {
    el.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="task" id="task">
  <h1>To-do list</h1>
  <input type="text" , id="myinput" , placeholder="Task">
  <button onclick="newTask()" type="button" , class="button" id="button"> Add</button>
</div>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try querying off of the event target and locating the closest ancestor of type `<LI>`.

```js
close[i].onclick = (e) => {
  var li = e.target.closest('li');
  li.style.display = "none";
}
```

The click handler can now be moved to its own self-contained function. Also, you should just remove the element instead of making it invisible.

```js
function handleRemove(e) {
  e.target.closest('li').remove();
};
```

#### Fixed example

```js
let myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
let i;
let close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

function handleRemove(e) {
  e.target.closest('li').remove();
};

function newTask() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let value = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  let t = document.createTextNode(value);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (value === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myinput").value = "";

  let button = document.createElement("button");
  let text = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  button.className = "close";
  button.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(button);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = handleRemove;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="task" id="task">
  <h1>To-do list</h1>
  <input type="text" , id="myinput" , placeholder="Task">
  <button onclick="newTask()" type="button" , class="button" id="button"> Add</button>
</div>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

parentElement is undefined. The parentElement is a method of a node. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement

You need to change your code to the following assuming you want to hide the parent `ul` element.

```
  
let myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
let i;
let close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

function newTask() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let value = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  let t = document.createTextNode(value);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (value === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myinput").value = "";

  let button = document.createElement("button");
  let text = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  button.className = "close";
  button.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(button);
  
   for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = () => {
      var div = li.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete the list get the object, i do it here with example name.

A li element its normally a child from a

Let's say the ul object id is listobject:

```
function clearList() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("listobject");
  ul.innerHTML = ""
}
```

And if you want to add single listitems you can do:

```
function addItem() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("listobject");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("new item"));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Just asign your onclick event from button to the function

Hope that help you
Happy coding ✌️